How to set device volume to certain level using Appium?
So I am automating an application and to increase or decrease the volume I am using
driver.press_keycode(24) // Increase 
driver.press_keycode(24) // Decrease

But I want to set to certain level directly, like set volume to 50%, how to do this?

How bout trying adb command?
adb shell service call audio {code} i32 {volume level}
driver.press_keycode(24) // Decrease. ==> It must be driver.press_keycode(25)
